# bitbucket pipeline calling YAML anchors from within a for loop

Tags: azure, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a YAML anchor that deploys logic-apps. I want the pipeline to look for logic apps in subdirectory and loop through each one and deploy it. Here's my deploy-logicapp anchor

```
  - step: &deploy-logicapp
      name: Deploy logic app
      script:
        - source environment.sh
        - pipe: microsoft/azure-arm-deploy:1.0.2
          variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_CLIENT_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_SECRET
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT
              AZURE_LOCATION: $AZURE_LOCATION
              AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
              AZURE_DEPLOYMENT_TEMPLATE_FILE: 'logic-apps/$DIR/template.$DEPLOYMENT_SLOT.json'
```

so in my pipeline, I loop through all the subdirectories and this works, it echoes each $DIR

```
      - step:
          script:
            - cd logic-apps
            - for DIR in $(ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); do echo $DIR ; done
```

What I want to do is inside this loop I want to call my YAML anchor with the $DIR environment variable. I have tried a number of ways. The problem is the for loop is inside bash and not YAML so I can not call it.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to actually call a YAML anchor from a for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible, I solved it with the bash script below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I need to do everything from the azure command line. Here's the bash script that loops through all directories and deploy them.

```
#!/bin/bash
az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT
for DIR in $(ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); do
    az deployment group create --resource-group $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP --template-file $DIR/template.$DEPLOYMENT_SLOT.json --name $DIR
done
```

Next is to only deploy those that have changed :)